# Add an extra page in the end of list for pageview.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to add an extra page in the end of list for pageview.builder, below is the code I try to achieve this effect, but in the end I got the error :

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2
```

here is the code:

```
 PageView.builder(
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  controller: _pageController,
                  itemCount: controller.homeProfiles.length + 1,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                    final Profile profile = controller.homeProfiles[index];
                   
                    //below I try to add an extra page in the end of list
                        return index <= controller.homeProfiles.length
                            ? ProfileWidget(
                                profile: profile,
                              )
                            : AddExtraPage();
                      },
                    ),
```

What shall I do to achieve always add an extraPage in the end of this pageview? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be less than `<` instead less than or equal `<=` operator. Also, `controller.homeProfiles[index]` should be inside the ternary if. Like the following snippet:

```dart
return index < controller.homeProfiles.length
    ? ProfileWidget(
        profile: controller.homeProfiles[index],
      )
    : AddExtraPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this it will solve your issue.
In below firstly you will check if `index == length` then you will show your `ExtraPage` otherwise your `ProfileWidget`.

```
  return index == controller.homeProfiles.length
                  ? AddExtraPage()
                  : ProfileWidget(profile: profile);
```